# Does Apache Curator auto-discover new Zookeeper nodes?

Tags: apache-curator

Let's say I initialize Curator giving it a single Zookeeper server to `CuratorFrameworkFactory#newClient`. Will Apache Curator automagically discover the other servers in the ensemble? Or will I always need to specify all servers in the connection string for it to gracefully switch over to other leader when/if that happens?